# Stop TfsSource from checking in files with no pending changes?

Tags: build, tfs

I'm facing a problem with the activity "TfsBuildExtensions.Activities.TeamFoundationServer.TfsAction.Checkin" in my build scripts. In my TFS setup, I have a lot of dependency replication going on, and it works like a charm...but it checks in a "new version" of the files after every build, even though it recongnizes that "No pending changes where found" in the build log, and the history log filles up with lots of build script checkins.

Any idea how this can be solved?

TfsBuildExtensions.Activities.TeamFoundationServer.TfsAction.Checkin doesn't seems to have the /force option in properties :(

Too bad I can't post pictures, due to being a new member :)

Thanks in advance.